# Operação XOR filtrando os valores da minha lista nas colunas do DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, lista, loop, pandas

Tenho várias listas e um único dataframe, meu objetivo é filtrar minhas colunas que contém os mesmos valores da minha lista e criar uma operação XOR de forma dinâmica. Ao encontrar o meu resultado XOR igual a 0, a linha desse meu resultado deverá ser excluída.

```
l1 = ['macao', 'banana']
l2 = ['uva','pera']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(5, 5)),
                  columns=['uva', 'pera', 'maca', 'banana', 'melao'])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Operação XOR.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado após deletar as linhas onde a operação XOR é igual a 0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para criar a coluna do XOR, você pode fazer assim:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(5, 5)),
              columns=['uva', 'pera', 'maca', 'banana', 'melao'])



df['XOR maca_banana'] = df['maca'] ^ df['banana']
```

O símbolo  ' ^ ' no código acima é uma representação da função de XOR, em Python.

Para remover as linhas cujas colunas de XOR possuem pelo menos um valor igual a 0, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
df.drop(df[ (df['XOR maca_banana'] == 0) | (df['XOR uva_pera'] == 0) ].index, inplace=True)
```